# How would I go about invoking the ui from within a DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, exe

This may be too broad a question, but I have a `DLL` that contains a UI.  It is currently invoked by an `EXE`.  What steps would I do to try and invoke the UI within the DLL?  Or put another way, how would I go about teasing out the code that would invoke the UI as it happens in the `EXE`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "invoke"?

Comment: @MrEricSir, by that I mean bring up.  I need the framework to be running in a very specific instance where the `EXE` is not available.

Comment: How is the UI currently accessed by applications? Do you have the import library and necessary header files? There's a _lot_ of information missing from your post.

Comment: Post your example. Could you call dll functions? Do you know about windows events loop? What about type of the UI? Dialogs or standard windows or maybe Qt? When you need to show UI? The task is interesting but you definitely have to clarify it more precisely.

Comment: @avesus, unfortunately I can't post any type of example.  This is for a very large application that I need to generate some tests for.  I am trying to shoehorn Microsoft's Unit Testing system into testing particular pieces of this monolithic code base, but to do that I need the framework up and running when the testing is initiated.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, yes, I know that there is a lot missing.  This problem is very large and I don't know where to start.  Yes, I have the import library and necessary header files.  This is because I have the source code for both the `EXE` and the `DLL`.

Comment: @avesus, I do have a general understanding about message loops.  The UI is a modified MDI framework.  I need to show the UI prior to the execution of the tests and then tear it down when the tests are complete.

Comment: If it's that big and complicated that you don't know where to start how do you expect us to provide you any relevant information with the little information you've given us?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, I'm asking because if I don't ask, I won't get anything.  I was hoping that I might be able to get some ideas as to where I might poke around.  What I might be looking for to bring this system up.

Comment: A DLL doesn't contain a UI. It contains code and resources. A DLL is also not invoked by an EXE. It is loaded (or mapped) into a process. As asked, your question doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: @IInspectable, a DLL can contain anything that an EXE has.  It can contain data and code.  The code has a set of instructions to interface with the system and has an interface so some other EXE/DLL can execute the code that it has.  In this case it contains code that generates a UI written against the MFC framework.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have access to source for both dll and executable that uses it. so what you are doing is writing a host for that dll from scratch.

- Create a MFC application from VS project templates (make it the same kind as main executable, dialog, single document, multiple document, etc).
- Look at what function dll exports, also look at its headers and best of all -- documentation.
- Search source code of main exe and find the places the dll functions are called.
- Figure out what is being done and why.
- Narrow down scenarios you want to reproduce (initialize dll, show basic UI and tear down)
- Start reproducing that code in your example app.
- Copy the dll call, see what parameters it takes, see how those are initialized, etc.
- Fix errors as they come up.